# Flutter: setState working on first try but not after response = await

Tags: json, flutter, dart, setstate, barcode-scanner

I am trying to use setState in an async Future to change some text on the page.

I have tried setting the state on different lines. If I set the state after `Response response = await get` nothing happens.

```dart
try {
    String barcodeRaw = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
    setState(() => barcode = barcodeRaw); // Works great and gives numbers

    Response response = await 
    get('https://www.datakick.org/api/items/'+barcodeRaw);
    setState(() => barcode = barcodeRaw); // Changes the value but does not change the text

    Map<String, dynamic> barcodeJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
    String barcodeNew = "${barcodeJson['brand_name']}";
    setState(() => barcode = barcodeNew); // Changes the value but does not change the text

    print(barcode); // Value is updated correctly
}
```

All 3 setStates change the value of "barcode" but only the first changes the text displayed.

Comment: I can't seem to find the place where you actually assign a new value to barcodeRaw. Also, without knowing your UI code it will be ver difficult to give any advice

Comment: I don't see any problems. If the last print is really printing something that is different than what you see on the app, there is something else that's going wrong. You can add print statements/breakpoints in the build function to ensure that the correct value gets its way to the build function.

Answer (score -1):

### Identify Problems

By calling `setState`, `StatefulWidget` will trigger build function **once**.

So, we need to add some 'callback' as soon the build function has completely executed by using this code

```dart
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(someFunction);
```

### Full Code

```dart
void firstChange() async {
  try {
    String barcodeRaw = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
    setState(() => barcode = barcodeRaw);

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(secondChange); // bind Callback

    print(barcode);
  } catch (e) {
    print("error");
  }
}

void secondChange(Duration duration) async {
  try {
    String barcodeRaw = barcode;
    Response response = await http.get('https://www.datakick.org/api/items/' + barcodeRaw);
    setState(() => barcode = barcodeRaw);

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(thirdChange); // bind Callback

    print(barcode);
  } catch (e) {
    print("error");
  }
}

void thirdChange(Duration duration) async {
  try {
    Map<String, dynamic> barcodeJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
    String barcodeNew = "${barcodeJson['brand_name']}";
    setState(() => barcode = barcodeNew);
    print(barcode);
  } catch (e) {
    print("error");
  }
}
```

#### Demo

[image: Demo]

I strongly suggest you to go to [complete code](https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_tricky_layout/blob/master/lib/k_screen/post_frame.dart) for better understanding.

In my example, I make `Future.delayed` calls **instead** make any API call or BarcodeScan which I think its **equivalent.**

#### Best Practice

I suggest you to take a look at [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package.

I also have the example that you can build yourself [here](https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_sqlite_api_provider/tree/master/lib/c_screen/2_auto_init_chaining)

And use notifyListener simplicity rather than having multiple-callbacks that are hard to manage

Comment: If I comment out the first 2 setStates it still won't update the text.

Comment: WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(thirdChange);  will not be called you comment out the first 2 setState. so thirdChange function only will be triggered after build. you can see lifecycle here https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzElL.png

Comment: I added my answer and new demo, hopely it helps for better understanding. You can build it by yourself as I shared complete repo of it